# how to add the first 10 records of a rank with measure in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to add the first 10 values of a rank. I'm doing the rank like this:

```
Rank_4 = IF(HASONEVALUE('inci soporte_nuevo'[pb_cod_nom]),
RANKX(ALLSELECTED('inci soporte_nuevo'[pb_cod_nom]),
CALCULATE(SUM('inci soporte_nuevo'[nro_inc])),,DESC))
```

it is from a table of incidents that occur at sites. column nro_inc is equal to 1 as I use it to count the records.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9R3A.png)

How can I make the first 10 records of this image add up, I mean 660 + 636 + 629 ...

Comment: You can use visual level filter using measure Rank_4 with less than 11.

Comment: but rank is a measure, I can't use it as a filter

Comment: As returned value is numeric, you can. Set measure < 11. Another option is to set Top 10 filter on your value column.

Comment: also this sum I want to use in another measure, that is why my question

Comment: You can use any measure into another, unless any circular dependency arise.

Comment: It will not be circular, because I want to create this measure in another table. but you could interpret it in an answer as it should do that measurement so that it adds the first 10 values of the rank